# VS Code Go to Symbol now(v1.42) showing variables, object and properties. How to customize?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Go to Symbol now(v1.42) showing variables, properties in php and object, variables and properties in js.

How to customize it?

How to only show classes, methods and functions in PHP? Similarly for js show functions and methods.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no such possibility to configure the list of symbol types. The only workaround I know is to add `:` character, it will group the symbols by type (classes, methods, functions etc).